# Why does my javascript only fire when the code is repeated?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue where I can only get my code to fire if I repeat it. See the below example. While the code is nearly identical if I take either of the two scripts out the code doesn't function with just one, yet if I run both the script fires fine, but only one instead of two. give it a go.

This works (but only one script fires):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href + "";
document.write('<script type="application/javascript" src="https://testdomain.com/mik21?add=2140535&mik21=' + url + '"/>');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href + "";
document.write('<script type="application/javascript" src="https://testdomain.com/mik?add=2140535&mik=' + url + '"/>');
</script>
```

This does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href + "";
document.write('<script type="application/javascript" src="https://testdomain.com/mik21?add=2140535&mik21=' + url + '"/>');
</script>
```

Or this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href + "";
document.write('<script type="application/javascript" src="https://testdomain.com/mik?add=2140535&mik=' + url + '"/>');
</script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas? this is definitely the weirdest thing I've seen in a while.

Thanks,

Comment: don't use document.write is my first hint, who knows why that's even still valid in browsers since about 2005

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: what is before the first instance of `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Comment: Worked fine here in a jsFiddle

Comment: `document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle envioriment` mäh

Comment: is there something like `<script src="..." />`

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write , Link may have the answer for  the question. Just read the text inside heading "The benefits and uses"

Comment: @feeela True, but the above code works fine in jsFiddle anyway :)

Comment: @RGraham the individual scripts work on their own or they only work together? i can only see them working together.

Comment: @ArunPJohny nothing, this is the whole script.

Comment: Try it with `<script …></script>`. `script` requires a closing tag.

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you elaborate? i'm new to JS.

Comment: can you share your complete html.... the code you have shared should work....

Comment: the code you shared works.. check in developer tools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just tested this:

Consider the source

```
data:application/javascript;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coIlRlc3QiKTs=
```

This points to the following code:

```
console.log("Test");
```

---

This snippet below generates

```
<script src="data:application/javascript;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coIlRlc3QiKTs="/>
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<script>
document.write('<script src="data:application/javascript;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coIlRlc3QiKTs="/>');
</script>
<div>B</div>
```

---

However, this snippet below generates

```
<script src="data:application/javascript;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coIlRlc3QiKTs="></script>
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<script>
document.write('<script src="data:application/javascript;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coIlRlc3QiKTs="></'+'script>');
</script>
<div>B</div>
```

---

The first snippet logs `"Test"` but *doesn’t display “B” in the HTML*. The second works properly. In the [Real-time HTML Editor](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/) not even `"Test"` gets logged for the first one. The implication of that is that all the HTML below the `<script/>` (which is inserted as `<script>`) gets consumed as [Salman A’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203130/why-does-my-javascript-only-fire-when-the-code-is-repeated#31204643) points out.

This is because the only valid syntax for `<script>` tags is `<script></script>` and **not** `<script/>`.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that your script tag is broken. A `<script>` tag must be closed by `</script>`.
Now here is what happens:

**Example 1**

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src="test.js"/>');
</script>
```

Produces the following markup HTML:

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src="test.js"/>');
</script>
<script src="test.js">
  </body>
  </html>
```

In general, browsers do not execute a `<script>` block until they find the corresponding `</script>`. There is no explicit closing tag in the above example so the browser ignores the tag.

**Example 2**

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src="test.js"/>');
</script>
This HTML will be consumed
<script>
  document.write('<script src="test.js"/>');
</script>
```

Produces the following output:

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src="test.js"/>');
</script>
<script src="test.js">
  This HTML will be consumed
  <script>
  document.write('<script src="test.js"/>');
</script>
```

Notice that the dynamically written script tag is not closed. The browser will match this tag with the second `</script>` in the markup; everything in-between (incorrectly) becomes part of this tag.

**Solution**

When using document.write, make sure that you close `<script>` tags properly. But note that you cannot use `</script>` as-is inside JavaScript code since it signals end of script block. You can use the following trick:

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src="test.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: Note: If someone is wondering why the browser does not raise syntax errors, the answer is: the browser will ignore script tag's content when the `src` attribute is present.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href + "";
document.write('<script type="application/javascript" src="https://testdomain.com/mik21?add=2140535&mik21=' + url + '"></scr'+'ipt>');
document.close();
</script>
```

To prevent js from crashing, i've split the `<script>` tag into two strings.